# Have UIButton display "Add to Contacts" popover

Tags: ipad, uibutton, uitextfield, contacts, addressbook

My Application is on an iPad.  I have a UIButton that I would like to mimic the action of when a user selects a phone number from a UITextField, and then selects the "Add to Contacts" button from the popover.  In short, I would like that popover to appear over my UIButton when a user presses it.

I was just wondering if anyone has thought of possible ways to accomplish this, or is my only option to add contacts in iOS is to use ABUnknownPersonViewController?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should link the button to perform a method that pushes an ABNewPersonViewController to the  top of the ABPeoplePickerNavigationControler, where the user can then go and enter the data. This is what the NewPerson vc is made for.